# no any conda or pip command is working. how to get my base environment in anaconda prompt?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, virtualenv, conda, prompt

I have install many libraries in anaconda prompt. I never set any environment name. I all done in base environment. But while i try to change the environments in anaconda prompt. Now anaconda prompt starts with  commands like this: **0it [00:00, ?it/s]** every time i open prompt and it is now don't recognizing any conda or pip commands.

I try to deactivate the bat but don't work.

Also, delete the **.condarc** file

Now it is not showing any environments. It shows this on any command i enter:
[image]

Also, anaconda navigator is not opening. I tried to open it using prompt
[image: I tried to open it using prompt]

i don't want to reinstall the anaconda again as i don't want to install 100+ libraries again.

So anyone have any idea about how this problem can be solved.

Comment: What does `where conda` output?

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand

Comment: I don't know if it's the issue in this particular case, but installing packages in your base environment and using it for development is likely to break things.

Comment: yeah, unfortunately i made that mistake. Now i can't able to do anything.